# c++ qt Dialog 'OK' button after Mainwindow set image

Tags: c++, qt, button

I want new form from 'OK' click after

```
From Mainwindow label Set image
image path : ./org/org.jpg
```

addim.h

```
private slots:
void on_buttonBox_accepted();  <---- 'OK' button
```

addim.cpp

```
void AddIm::on_ADdimg_cliekd()
system("raspistill -w 480 -h 360 -q 20 -o aaa.jpg -t 2");
QPixmap pix("./org/org.jpg);      
ui2->QWidjet_org->setPixmap(pix);  <--- QWidjet_org this label
```

Comment: Trying my best here:  you want an alert dialog with an "OK" button that loads a new form when clicked, on which there is an image from a label's text in MainWindow ?

Comment: addim.cpp

QPixmap pix("./org/org.jpg");

ui2->QWidjet_org->setPixmap(pix);

this QWidjet_org <<<---label

Comment: That's what I understand too

Comment: Creating an other form with the image would be the best here, with a public function to change the image, and then showing it when you click the button.

Comment: You have a picture in the main window and you want to update the image with the path in the label when you click OK?

Comment: yes i want Dialog(addim.cpp) button 'OK' after main window  label to the image set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do a minimal code that works:

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "dialog.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    //This will change the image in the main window
    void buttonHere();
    //This will change the image in the dialog box
    void buttonDialog();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Dialog dialog;
    //We need to save the image in QImage so it doesn't disappear
    QImage image;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QObject::connect(ui->pushButton_here, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), SLOT(buttonHere()));
    QObject::connect(ui->pushButton_dialog, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), SLOT(buttonDialog()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::buttonHere()
{
    //We load the image
    image.load(ui->label->text());
    //We set the label image
    ui->label_2->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
}

void MainWindow::buttonDialog()
{
    //We call the function that changes the dialog image
    dialog.setImage(ui->label->text());
    //We show the dialog
    dialog.show();
}
```

Dialog.h

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

    //This function changes the image
    void setImage(QString path);

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
    //We need to save the image in QImage so it doesn't disappear
    QImage image;
};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

Dialog.cpp

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::setImage(QString path)
{
    //We load the image
    image.load(path);
    //We set the label image
    ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
}
```

You get this result

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDQD7.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbrsA.png

Answer (score 0):

You should create a resource file, import your picture in it and then use the following example code:

```
QPixmap pixmap_btn_hw(":/new/myPrefix/btn_hardware.png");
QIcon ButtonIcon_hw(pixmap_btn_hw);
ui->hardware_btn->setIcon(ButtonIcon_hw);
ui->hardware_btn->setIconSize(pixmap_btn_hw.rect().size());
ui->hardware_btn->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
```

To start an external program, "sytem()" is a bad idea. The following is much better:

```
QProcess *prpr = new QProcess();
prpr->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
prpr->start("raspistill -w 480 -h 360 -q 20 -o aaa.jpg -t 2");
if (!prpr->waitForFinished())
{
   // there was an error
}
else
{
   // command worked!
}
```

Comment: What difference does using a resource file make, for askers actual problem? Also, how is using `waitForFinished` any better than `system`?